# Cannot pass specific portion of Fortran array without errors

Tags: arrays, fortran, dimensions, subroutine, fortran95

As mentioned in the title, I am having trouble when trying to pass part of an array into a subroutine (called `Example`, see below) in Fortran 95.

My code has the following layout:

```
    PROGRAM Code

    DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(72) :: Array1

!Method 1
    CALL EXAMPLE(Array1)

!Method 2
    CALL EXAMPLE(Array1(1:72))

    END PROGRAM Code


    SUBROUTINE EXAMPLE(Array1)

    DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(72) :: Array1

    END
```

Method 1 (see above) works fine, however when method 2 is used, an error message appears saying that this argument is too small for its declared size. If I declared the size as 72 and I pass from 1:72, why would this result in the above error.

The reason I cant use method 1 is because the size of the array may change/the portion of the array I pass to the subroutine may be different.

For example I may want to pass the first 36 elements (ie 1:36) and then pass the last 36 elements (ie 37:72) to the subroutine. I have also made sure to change the declared size of the array in `EXAMPLE` accordingly to match what I'm inputting.

Any idea as to why this is not working for me?

Comment: I am a bit surprised the first call worked for you. If I run this through gfortran, I get "Warning: More actual than formal arguments in procedure call at (1)" for both calls.

Comment: I should have added, I can get it to run with gfortran as is, as well as with Plato Silverfrost on 'Release Win32' with no errors. When I try compiling using Plato Silverfrost on 'Checkmate .NET' or 'Checkmate Win32' however,I am getting the error I put in my original post. I am not too familiar with the difference between the two compilers on Plato (maybe the issue is not with my code, maybe it is something unique to Plato Checkmate?)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to use an assumed-shape array, where the dummy argument assumes the shape of the actual argument.  For this, the subroutine needs an explicit interface; the best way is to put it into a module.

So, like this:

```
module foo
  implicit none
contains
  subroutine example(array1)
    double precision, dimension(:), intent(in) :: array1
    print *,size(array1)
    print *,array1
  end subroutine example
end module foo

program main
   use foo
   implicit none
   double precision, dimension(72) :: array1
   array1 = 42.d0
   call example (array1)
   call example (array1(1:36))
end program main
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I forgot to include that in my question above, however I did include it in my actual code. I've edited my original post

Comment: In the original code, the dummy argument was missing.  This no longer matches the question, so I am editing the question rather heavily.

Comment: @IanH: Thanks for the edit - I never can get assumed shape and assumed size terminology straight. One of the worse terminology decisions in computer science.